# Shorthand in Ruby, Artoo.io

Tags: ruby, syntax, celluloid

I am looking for an explanation for what's going on at the top of [artoo.io](http://artoo.io/documentation/platforms/keyboard/) robots. There is a declaration at the top of this example using the keyboard driver:

```
require 'artoo'

connection :keyboard, adaptor: :keyboard
device :keyboard, driver: :keyboard, connection: :keyboard
```

It seems that some shorthand/alternative syntax is displayed, and I'd love an explanation of that shorthand. I understand the alternative hash syntax: `:adapter => :keyboard`.

What is going on in those last two lines of code above? What is `connection`? Is it a class inside `artoo` that is being initialized? Why is there no `new`? Where does `:keyboard` come from? If there is an alternative syntax that represents the relationships more explicitly, could you show that as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great question. It might be a duplicate but I couldn't find one and this is the sort of thing that is tricky for smart programmers who are new to Ruby.

First, to your question: What is `connection`?

It is a *method call*. In some cases it can be hard to tell what is a method and what is a variable, because it just depends on how they were defined. But in this case it is clear because `connection` has parameters after it. In ruby, a method can be called like this:

```
foo
```

In that case it is a method that takes no parameters. Or it can look like this:

```
foo 1, 2, 3
```

That is a method with three parameters. Or it can look like this:

```
foo(1, 2, 3)
```

That is the same method, but with a slightly different syntax (which is more familiar to people experiences in c-mimicing languages like c, C++, Java, Javascript, C#, etc...)

So when you see parameters listed after a bare word, with no operators between, it is a sure sign it's a method call.

Now to break down your code entirely.

```
require 'artoo'
```

This is technically a method call. You're calling the `require` method and passing a single parameter of the literal string `'artoo'`. As you probably know, `require` loads an external ruby file into the current file.

```
connection :keyboard, adaptor: :keyboard
```

This is a method call with some [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar):

You know right away that `connection` is a method call because it has parameters after it (i.e. no operator between `connection` and what comes after). But what parameters?

`:keyboard`: is a [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html), which is ruby's equivalent of an [intern'd string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_intern_pool).

`adaptor: :keyboard` is a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html).

Ruby has two primary hash syntaxes:

```
{key => value}
```

Where `key` and `value` are any objects, or:

```
{key: value}
```

Where `key` is a bare literal Symbol and `value` is any object. Also, to keep code clean, when you pass a Hash as the *last* parameter to a method, you can leave off the `{` and `}` because it is unambiguous. It ends up giving you a clean "named parameter" style method call:

```
do_something_to my_person, kindness: 10, aggressiveness: 2
```

In your code:

```
connection :keyboard, adaptor: :keyboard
```

You have the alternate hash syntax (symbol keys) with the `{` and `}` left off. The whole line is 100% equivalent to:

```
connection(:keyboard, {:adaptor => :keyboard})
```

Your last line:

```
device :keyboard, driver: :keyboard, connection: :keyboard
```

Is the same thing. Equivalent to:

```
device(:keyboard, {:driver => :keyboard, :connection => :keyboard})
```

It just looks nicer (once you get used to it).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `connection` and `device` are methods. The `adapter: :keyboard`, `driver: :keyboard` and `:connection: :keyboard` bits are parameters being passed as a hash to those methods. The first parameters passed to connection() and device() are not being passed in a hash.

The same code could be rewritten like this:

```
connection :keyboard, { adaptor => :keyboard }
device :keyboard, { driver => :keyboard, connection => :keyboard }
```